# How to clone db in adminer

Tags: php, adminer

How to clone db in adminer?
right now there is no way to copy an existing db to any new db or
any existing db to existing db

now if we copy tables from one db to another then there is no way to select functions and stored procedures.

so is there any solution for it?

[image]

**in adminer we have the above feature to copy tables to another db but no option to select events and functions**

Comment: Make dump file of first database and import into another database. That's doable even with plain SQL

Comment: but like in phpmyadmin we have option of clone db, is it possible with adminer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way (using adminer), is using the "Export" button.

Make sure you [select "Routines" and "Events"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zREyZ.png) to also export your triggers and stored procedures.

After exporting, you might have to create a new database as you wish and then use the Import function, select the file you have exported, and execute.

If your export dump file is bigger than 128MB, I recommend using [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 1):

KT,

you can easily export a .sql dump of your database in adminer.

[export database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJroZ.png)

Now, you just have to import your dump and you should be good to go!

[import database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj195.png)